# When setting height to 100vh, page appears more than twice the size of the screen vertically

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this very simple code. The way I understand it, setting the height to 100vh for body should fit everything inside the visible screen, but when I run it, the page appears more than twice the size of the visible screen. I have to set height for body to 40-50vh to fit everything inside the visible screen. I am using latest Chrome on a 1366x768 screen. I know I am missing something very simple here. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

textarea { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<textarea></textarea>

<textarea></textarea>

<button>POST</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you have overflow. You have 2 `<textarea>` with height 100% stacked on top each other, so 200%. Also, you have the default body margin. Add `overflow: hidden;` and `margin: 0;` to your `body` style and you'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening is the body is still the size of the view port but the text area is set to 100% of the view port and as you you have 2 text areas it is overflowing the body container to be 200% of the body. In my snippet I have added a border to the body so you can see what is going on

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    border:5px solid red;
}

textarea { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<textarea></textarea>

<textarea></textarea>

<button>POST</button>

</body>
</html>
```

So change the text area height to 48% so you can still fit the post button in there aswell.

Comment: Thanks. I was just thinking that when max-height is set to 100vh, it won't expand no matter what. Apparently there is no way to make a container non-expandable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `textarea`'s `height` to `100%` that's why it is taking **100% + 100% + button's height** - that's more than twice! Change your `textarea`'s `height` to `auto` so that it will take only needed sapce.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
textarea { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>POST</button>
```